# Sending a csv file's content as a table in a mail from python

Tags: python, csv, email, unix

I have a csv file . Want to send the content of this file as a table through email from python. I am working in unix environment.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Found a way!

Was writing the CSV file from a dataframe object.
Converted the df to html table using "to_html" and send using sendmail().

Is there any better way ?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Define table. HTML?

Comment: I tried using smtplib. But it didn't work.